# How to schedule a URL-based API call in Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, url, api

I have this DNS dynamic service and I need to find a way to call the API to update my dynamic IP.

The URL that needs to be call is just a .php with some GET parameters.

Is there a way to do it in CMD? Or maybe Powershell? I really looking for a very lightweight way, because this will be triggered every 1 hour.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download [cURL for Windows](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html) and schedule a job that calls it, or a `.cmd` file which does what you need.

Answer (score 2):

In powershell v2 there is no built-in cmdlet for this, but it's still fairly simple using the `WebClient` class:

```
$wc = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.DownloadString('http://www.google.com') | Out-Null  # ignore the response if just calling an API
```

Put that in a file with a `.ps1` extension, then invoke via a schedule like this

```
powershell.exe -executionpolicy unrestricted -file C:\scripts\webapi.ps1
```

In powershell v3 (default in Win8/Server 2012, also now released for downlevel OS), there is a new built-in cmdlet `Invoke-WebRequest` which does bascially the same thing, but is packaged nicely and has some other bells and whistles.